# How to set New Template of a workitem as default in TFS?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, workitem

In TFS 2017, I created a new template for a workitem (out of the box) with the necessary fields. How can this template be set as default, so that any workitems created further will have the new template.

I could see [bulk update](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/productivity/work-item-template) of the Workitems, but not setting it as default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't support to set the template as a default template currently in TFS 2017.

As a workaround, you could set default vaules for fields in workitem definition files instead of using workitem template.

For example, set the default vaule for Description field:

1. [Export the workitem definition file](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-manage-wits) using witadmin command:
2. Add a default rule for Description field:

   `<FIELD name="Description" refname="System.Description" type="HTML">
         <DEFAULT from="value" value="*****" />
   </FIELD>`
3. Save and import your workitem definition file.

[Another workaround](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/productivity/work-item-template#add-a-template-link-to-the-dashboard) is you could add template links to a **Markdown widget** that appear on your team dashboard in the web portal. Then you could  create workitem from this links on dashboard.

In the [Markdown widges](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/widget-catalog#markdown), config links like `[link description](Url)`.

```
[Bug -- Template1](http://fabrikamfiber:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/Fabrikam%20Fiber/Web/_workItems?_a=new&witd=Bug&templateId=15ffa521-7a1d-486e-9f71-a58c0b338d87)
```

Comment: Thank you Tingting for the response. From the first approach I cannot add default value of more than 255 characters (my case has more than 500 characters). Probably I can convince my client to use the second approach using Markdown widget with the new template.